# ISR in mips isn't restoring my registers correctly

Tags: assembly, mips, interrupt-handling, isr, plp-mips

```
.org 0x10000000

li $sp, 0x10fffffc    # Stack pointer initialization
li $s0, sseg_lut    # Lookup table address used by sseg_display
lui $s1, 0xf070    # Interrupt controller register
lui $s2, 0xf0a0    # Seven segment display

# ****************************
# TODO: enable interrupts below
# ****************************

li $t0, 0b11    #Value to set the mask to. Set bit pos 0 and 1 to high so we can use interrupts and timer
sw $t0, 0($s1)    #Store the value to the mask

li $t1, 0xffffffff #max overflow for ISR
li $t2, 0x00000064 #value of 100. Subtract from the max to get 100 cycles.
li $t3, 0xf0600000 #value of the timer
subu $t1, $t1, $t2 #subtract 100 from the timer's max
sw $t1, 0($t3) #write new overflow value to the timer

li $t4, 0xf0200000 #address of LEDS
li $t5, 0b11111111 #all ones to turn on all the LEDs
li $t6, 0b00000000 #all zeroes to turn off al the LEDs
li $iv, ISR    #store the vector


# NOTE: Do not add or modify any code within this main loop
main:
    #sw $t0, 0($s1) #If you un comment this, it works as intended.
    jal sseg_display
    nop
    addiu $a0, $a0, 1
    j main
    nop


# ****************************************
# TODO: add interrupt service routine below
# ****************************************
ISR:
    save
    lw $i0, 0($t4) #load value of LEDs to i0
    lw $i1, 4($s1) #loads the value of the status register to i1
    beq $t5, $i0, turnOffLED #t7 - 1
    nop            #t6 - 0
    bne $t5, $i0, turnOnLED
    nop
    turnOnLED:
        sw $t5, 0($t4)
        li $i1, 0b11
        j end
        nop
    turnOffLED:
        sw $t6, 0($t4)
        li $i1, 0b11
        j end
        nop
    end:
        sw $i1, 4($s1) #clear interrupts
        lw $i1, 0($s1) #get mask register
        ori $i1, $i1, 1
        restore
        jr $ir
        sw $i1, 0($s1) #resets all interrupts
```

The above code is supposed to flash LEDs every 100 clock cycles while a 7 segment display counts up in hex. That part was given to me so I know the counting works. My problem is that it will turn on the LEDs but not turn them off. I think my mask isn't being set correctly and global interrupts are disabled upon exiting the interrupt. I think the end function is what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We can't see `sseg_display`, `save`, or `restore`, which makes it hard to reason over the code.

Comment: This looks like PLP MIPS, which is rather different from regular MIPS regarding exception handling.  As far as I can see there's no stackoverflow tag for PLP or PLP MIPS, but the MIPS tag as the lone architectural tag is not really appropriate for this code.

Comment: Ok thank you. I tried adding PLP but it said it was a new tag and I didn't have enough reputation to create it. sseg_display is code that was given to me from my professor. So I didn't think it was necessary to attach. I know that part works. save and restore are pseudo-ops in PLP MIPS. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @ErikEidt I created the "plp-mips" tag and added some description for the tag. Unfortunately, my reputation is not high enough so the description for the tag must be peer reviewed first...

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I approved your tag edit by doing "improve and edit" to tighten up the wording for the excerpt.  (And put some of the original verbosity in [the main tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plp-mips/info)).  I don't know anything about PLPMIPS other than having seen a couple recent questions mention it.  Since you say it has some differences from real MIPS, yeah we need a tag for it.  We have tags for most of the simulators anyway because of their minor differences (and for questions about using their UIs), so yeah that's another reason to have a tag.

Comment: PLP MIPS repurposes some of the general registers for interrupt handling, and apparently does that instead of MIPS coprocessor 0, which is how (the other) MIPS provides the exception pc, and exception cause for example.  PLP MIPS has a `$iv`, a (repurposed) general purpose register which designates the interrupt handler address, whereas MIPS uses address 0x80000180, hard coded, and in kernel protected memory.